# How is this pure function able to modify non-private state?

Tags: d, pure-function

TDPL, p. 167:

> as long as the mutable state in a function is entirely *transitory* (i.e., allocated on the stack) and *private* (i.e., not passed along by reference to functions that may taint it), then the function can be considered pure.

```
import std.stdio : writeln;

struct M{
  int[4] _data;

  pure ref int opIndex(size_t i){ return _data[i]; }
}

pure M foo(ref M m){

  m[0] = 1234;
  return m;
}

void main(){

  M m1 = M([7, 7, 7, 7]);

  writeln(m1);
  foo(m1);
  writeln(m1);
}

// output:
// M([7, 7, 7, 7])
// M([1234, 7, 7, 7])
```

The mutable state is transitory because it's on the stack, correct?  But it's not private.  So how is `foo()` allowed to modify `m1`?

Comment: I've been trying to clean up the [tag:pure] tag, because it sometimes refers to pure virtual functions, sometimes to [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) and sometimes to [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_(programming_language)) - among others. But I don't know anything about [tag:d]. Could you confirm if my tag edit is appropriate? Would [tag:purely-functional] work for this question - I created [tag:pure-function], so if [tag:purely-functional] works I think it would be better to use the existing tag.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Pure as in [functional purity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), so pure-function would work for this question.  purely-functional, not so much.

Comment: .. although [Purely Functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional) is listed in that Wikipedia page's related links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pure` has been expanded a bit since the release of TDPL, since `pure` as TDPL describes turns out to be far too restrictive to be useful beyond simple math functions and the like. You can look at [the online documentation](http://dlang.org/function.html) for the current definition, but it essentially comes down to this:

1. `pure` functions cannot access any module-level or static variables which can be mutated during the course of the program (they must be `const` value types or `immutable` to be accessed from a `pure` function).
2. `pure` functions cannot call any functions which are not `pure`.
3. `pure` functions cannot perform I/O.

That's it. There are no other restrictions. However, there *are* additional restrictions required if a `pure` function is going to be optimized such that it only gets called one time even if it's used multiple times within a statement. Namely:

- The function's parameters must be `immutable` or implicitly convertible to `immutable`.

In theory that could be expanded to requiring that the function's *arguments* must be `immutable` or implicitly convertible to `immutable` (so that a function with `const` parameters could be optimized when it's given `immutable` arguments), but that's not currently the case.

Such `pure` functions are sometimes referred to as "strongly" `pure`, whereas those which cannot be optimized would be referred to as "weakly" `pure`. TDPL describes strongly `pure` functions. Weakly `pure` functions were added in order to make `pure` more generally usable.

While weakly `pure` functions *can* alter their arguments, they cannot alter the global state, so when they're called by strongly `pure` functions (which *can't* alter their arguments), the guarantee that the strongly `pure` function's return value will always be the same for the same arguments still holds. Essentially, because the weakly `pure` functions cannot mutate global state, they're part of the private state of the strongly `pure` function that they're called from. So, it's very much in line with what Andrei describes in section 5.11.1.1 *`pure` is as `pure` Does* in TDPL, except that the private state of the function has been expanded to allow functions which can alter its private state without altering global state.

Another major thing of note which has been added since TDPL with regards to `pure` is function attribute inference. `pure`, `nothrow`, and `@safe` are inferred for templated functions (though *not* for normal functions). So, if a templated function *can* be `pure`, now it *is* `pure`. Its purity depends on what it's instantiated with. So, it becomes possible to use `pure` with templated functions, whereas before, you usually couldn't, because if you made it `pure`, it wouldn't work with an impure function. But if you *didn't* make it `pure`, then you couldn't use it with a *`pure`* function, so it was a major problem for `pure`. Fortunately, attribute inference fixes that now though. As long as a templated function follows the rules listed above when it's instantiated, then it's considered `pure`.

Comment: I think I'll have to let this sink in and get used to things like `pure void opIndexAssign(T value, size_t i){ ... }`  and `pure T opIndex(size_t i) const{ ... }`

Comment: Just think of `pure` as meaning that the function can't access mutable global state, and then let the compiler optimize it when it can. Yes, the `pure` modifier ends up on more functions than those which are functionally `pure`, but _is_ still what makes the functionally `pure` functions possible and possible to be optimized.

Answer (score 5):

The `this` reference is considered part of the function's parameters, and since the function is weakly pure, you can modify the parameters. With the state of `this` considered part of the input, the function still fulfills the condition of having the same output with the same input.

Consider this entirely legal example, which outputs `2`:

```
import std.stdio : writeln;

struct S
{
    int foo = 0;
    pure void set(size_t i){ foo = i; }
}


void main()
{
    S s;
    s.set(2);
    writeln(s.foo);
}
```

As far as I know, after TDPL was released, the definition of pure was expanded. The book describes strongly-pure functions. After that, two developments have taken place: weakly-pure functions were added, which are allowed to mutate their parameters. Also, purity-inference has been added for template functions so that you can use a template function's instantiation as long as it's pure even if the template function isn't decorated with `pure`.